# Using Zend GData libarary for google analytics data

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using the Zend GData library to retrieve specific information from Google Analytics.

Basically I'm building the query using the Data Feed Query Explorer (from google) and then passing it to the library to generate the required data.

Issue:

The scripts works as expected except when i try to retrieve segment based information (for example Search traffic) with a metric (For example Visitors) .

The api is returning only the metrics' analytics and not the segments.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You maybe solved it, but the solution was to add v=2 to the query-string.. something like:
`https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?v=2&ids=[...]`